# Spring-data-redis: When within a transaction, get operations would return null

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data-redis

When working on a project using `redis`(4.0) and `spring-data-redis`.

It seems when within a transaction, the get operations would return null in java program.

e.g `HashOperation`'s `get()` method would return `null` when called between `multi()` and `exec()`.
But if put the `get()` before `multi()`, it can get the value.

So, why was that?

Answer (score 0):

After testing & thinking, I think this is the reasonable behavior, since transaction is executed within redis as an atomic operation, it's impossible to return a value in the middle of a transaction via network back to client, thus `null` is reasonable.

All the values are returned by the `exec()` methods as a `List` after execution of the transaction.

So, when debugging, in the middle of transaction, the value should be null, since it's not executed yet.

---

**Suggestion:**

If calculation within a transaction need to read value from redis, then just read those values first, before `multi()`.

Then between `multi()` and `exec()` only do update operations, but no read operations.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation it says "all readonly operations, such as KEYS are piped to a fresh (non thread bound) RedisConnection".  At onetime, i think it used to return the old value as reads were happening in different fresh connection. It seems behavior is changed recently as now i am seeing null values for all reads in a transaction. Can someone from spring-data-redis team make it clear the expected behavior.